# javascript closure functions with vars?

Tags: javascript, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Is there any applicable reason why one would declare functions with `var`s instead of just regular function definitions, especially when dealing with closure.

Obviously this probably does not make much sense until i demonstrate, so i shall!

*NOTE: I am using require.js to make this point obvious*

Example A:  How i normally do things

```
define(function() {

    function foo(x) {
        return x + 42;
    }

    function bar(y) {
        return y + foo(y);
    }

    var MyObject = function(config) {
        // some sweet stuff
    }

    MyObject.prototype = {
        myFun: function(x) {
            return bar(x)
        }
    }

    return MyObject;
})
```

Example B:  Ways i see it

```
define(function() {

    var foo = function(x) {
        return x + 42;
    }

    var bar = function(y) {
        return y + foo(y);
    }

    var MyObject = function(config) {
        // some sweet stuff
    }

    MyObject.prototype = {
        myFun: function(x) {
            return bar(x)
        }
    }

    return MyObject;
})
```

I assume there must be some difference between the two, maybe... :)

Thank you for your time and effort!

---

EDIT: 
Tried to ask the question in a more sensible way!

Comment: Perhaps, but mine is more in a closure situation where you would always have it defined first (it could be the same, and if is, sorry!)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz This is a different question - That one asks "what is the difference", this asks "Is there a reason to use one vs. the other"

Comment: @Jeff: I'd say the difference is the reason :-P

Comment: Even if you prefer method B, you should at least say `var foo = function foo(x) { ... }` so that the function shows up with the name `foo` in a stack trace.

Comment: All functions are closures in JavaScript, so it does not really make a difference.

Comment: If i am not mistaken there is an error in IE when doing the anonymous function naming

Comment: @RocketHazmat No, the difference isn't the reason, but it may imply the reason. That implication may be non-trivial however. The fact that the reason may be reasoned from the difference makes no difference to the reason for the difference in questions, which is that reasoning is hard. When it comes down to it that's the whole reason SO exists in the first place.

Comment: @Michael: Yep, older IE versions create duplicate functions if you use named function expressions.

Comment: @Jeff i am pretty sure my brain just divided by 0

Comment: @Jeff: `the reason may be reasoned from the difference makes no difference to the reason for the difference`. OW, my brain!

Comment: I disagree with the exact duplicate, but fine, what ever.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a gain. The Function Declarations you have in Example A get changed to function expressions and hoisted to the top of the closure so they look the same as what you have defined in your first example once the `var` declarations in Example B are hoisted.

The two forms you have are explicit assignment of *function expressions* and *function declarations.* Function declarations get changed into function expressions and the declaration itself is pulled up the top of the function (hoisting).

Read more here: http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/

Comment: I thought functions declared with `var` *don't* get hoisted.

Comment: As the "possible duplicate" suggests that they do not

Comment: They don't.  I just tested it: http://jsfiddle.net/c7w3s/

Comment: They do get hoisted. The *assignment* to the `var` does not. Your test is trying to invoke a something that is undefined at that point, because the assignment of a function to it doesn't apply until later.

Comment: See this fiddle for a good test case: http://jsfiddle.net/LtrP2/